# Would someone be able to walk me through plotMA function?

Tags: r, plot, genome

This is going to sound a bit stupid, but I'm a novice when it comes to R and I need to make an MA Plot out of some DE-Seq data I've been given.

This is an example of some  of the data:

| gene name | Mean | log2foldchange | padj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dop-1 | 110.53 | 0.27 | 0.20 |
| dop-2 | 208.23 | 0.36 | 0.04 |
| dop-3 | 158.59 | 0.61 | 0.01 |

I would be eternally grateful if someone would be kind enough to walk me through the steps of how to do this.
I've tried myself but I come across countless errors such as this one:

> Error in .local(object, ...) :
> When called with a data.frame, plotMA expects the data frame to have 3 columns, two numeric ones for mean and log fold change, and a logical one for significance.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Kind Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

From [`help("plotMA")`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DESeq/versions/1.24.0/topics/plotMA), we learn that `plotMA()` expects a data.frame with exactly 3 columns: mean, log fold change, and a logical column for significance.

You have mean, log fold change and adjusted p-value. So you need to make a significance column:

```
data$sig <- data$padj < 0.05
```

Now you can pass those three columns to `plotMA`:

```
library(DESeq2)
plotMA(data[,c("Mean","log2foldchange","sig")])
```

[image]

Sample Data:

```
data <- structure(list(gene_name = c("dop-1", "dop-2", "dop-3"), Mean = c(110.53, 
208.23, 158.59), log2foldchange = c(0.27, 0.36, 0.61), padj = c(0.2, 
0.04, 0.01)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```